# Why does Jinja2 render the string "on" to boolean True?

Tags: yaml, jinja2

I'm using Jinja2 with YAML and have the following structure:

```
{%- set example = [ (20, "on"), (40, "off")] %}

- name: example_yaml
    loop:
      {%- for value, state in example %}
        - TheNumber: {{ value }}
          TheState: {{ state }}
      {%- endfor %}
```

When the first loop is rendered, `TheNumber` is correct with `20`, but `TheState` ends up being `True`. I've looked through the documentation and have tried adding a string filter like this:

```
{{ state | string }}
```

But that did not work either. I have also Tried switching the string `"on"` to something else like `"StateShouldBeOn"` just to test with. With that I get what I expect `TheState = "StateShouldBeOn"`.

My question is, why is it that "on" renders to a boolean value?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'on' instead of "on". That should help.